# Converting multiple polygons to a single density raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I have 20 polygon shapefiles that overlap each other. I want to get a kernel density type raster from the polygons, but I am not sure if ArcMap (10.4.1) offers a tool to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [Kernel density](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm) tool you need to have point or polyline data:

> Calculates a magnitude-per-unit area from point or polyline features
>   using a kernel function to fit a smoothly tapered surface to each
>   **point** or **polyline**.

Kernel density available with Spatial Analyst license. If you have Spatial Analyst, then the tool is available for you.

The solution to your problem is as follows:

- Extract the centroids of the overlapping polygons
- Use Merge tool to merge all the points (in case the polygons are in
  separate shapefiles) into one shapefile.
- However, if all polygons are located in one shapefile, then you don't
  need to use Merge tool
- Finally, you can use Kernel density using centroid points as an
  input.